# Unknown reference to __dlopen in dlopen

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

`dlopen` is located in `libdl.a` but when I link my application against `libdl.a` , gcc linker throw this error : `unknow reference to __dlopen called in dlopen`

Should I import another `.a`?

Comment: @Guillaume07: Are you using Ubuntu? Maybe try installing `libc6-dev`.

Comment: for ar archives, the order matters too.

Comment: @phimuemue: yes i'm using Ubuntu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When I try to compile statically a `dlopen` mockup program, `gcc` (Archlinux/gcc version 4.6.1 20110819 (prerelease)) tells me:

```
$ gcc test.c  -ldl -static  
/tmp/ccsWe4RN.o: In function `main': test.c:(.text+0x13): 
warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires 
at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

and indeed, when I ran this script in `/usr/lib/`

```
for i in *.a; 
do 
    echo $i; 
    readelf -a $i | grep __dlopen;
done
```

I saw:

```
libc.a
16: 0000000000000080    69 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT    1 __dlopen
000000000000  002300000001 R_X86_64_64       0000000000000000 __dlopen + 0
35: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND __dlopen
```

so as per the first line, `libc.a` does define your missing symbole.

In my system, `gcc test.c  -ldl -static` is enough to make the application run, but

```
gcc <file> -static -ldl -lc
```

should fix the problem in your system.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the shared library `libdl.so` with

```
gcc -ldl ...
```

if you don't have a strong requirement on using the static version.

Comment: Not sure, but the linker seems to find `dlopen` (in `libdl.a`), but not `__dlopen` (which thus, seems to be somewhere else...).

Comment: in my system (Fedora), `dlopen` and `__dlopen` seem to be both in `libldl.so`, but *not defined* (but present) in `libldl.a` (seems strange!)

Comment: unfortunatly I have a strong requirement on using the static version

Comment: Why this requirement. It is extremely unusual.

Comment: Because static binaries are portable, don't have dynamic linking hell issues, etc, etc.