# undefined reference error in using dlopen in c++

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-compiling, dlopen, qpid

I am trying to cross-compile **apache-qpid** for an arm system from a debian.

There is `undefined reference to __dlopen` error, but it seems that it is related to the previous warning:

**using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking ...**

Here is the detail:

```
[ 86%] Linking CXX shared library libqpidcommon.so
CMakeFiles/qpidcommon.dir/qpid/sys/posix/Shlib.cpp.o: In function       
`qpid::sys::Shlib::load(char const*)':
/home/mert/qpid-cpp-0.34/src/qpid/sys/posix/Shlib.cpp:32: warning: Using   
'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared  
libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/home/mert/IDE/cVEND/00.00.14/bin/../arm-feig-linux-  
gnueabi/sysroot/usr/lib/libdl.a(dlopen.o): In function `dlopen':
dlopen.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to `__dlopen'
```

I do not know what is happening exactly and how to solve it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7526255/unknown-reference-to-dlopen-in-dlopen) there is a similiar thing, I tried to add `-static -ldl -lc` `C_FLAGS` but made no difference.

Any help appreciated.

**EDIT :**

EDIT :

I am not sure exactly what is solved the problem, but I think that -ldl was looking exactly for `libdl.so`, but in arm directory, it was `libdl-2.19.so`, thus, probably it was then looking for and finding in another directory. I have linked `libdl.so` to `libdl-2.19.so` and now it is compiling.

Answer (score 1):

The linker needs the options, not the compiler. See LDFLAGS.

https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables.html

> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the
>   linker, ‘ld’, such as -L. Libraries (-lfoo) should be added to the
>   LDLIBS variable instead.

Comment: The error is the oposite though. The project is compiling static binaries, which is not going to work when it's using dlopen() i.e. there should be no -static flag. I suspect this is due to either the toolchain the OP has installed, or the build system in qpid-apache picking up on some wrong settings, and it's quite hard to give any advice either way.

Answer (score 0):

If this error occurs during the make step try doing

```
make LIBS=-ldl
```

And make sure the library path is present in LDFLAGS

```
export LDFLAGS=-L<path/to/ldl>
```